# What does certbot change in apache2?

Tags: server, apache2, https

I used [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org) to enable secure http for a webpage that I host. Secure http is needed since users need to log in on the page and sending password in plain text is not a good idea. That website has it own domain name `secure.com`. Now I want to host another webpage on the same apache2 server with its own domain name `mypage.com`.

I have added separate config file for each page for the virtual server:

- secure.conf
- secure-le-ssl.conf
- mypage.conf

The problem I encounter is that my apache2 server after I used certbot does not accept http connections, but to enable https for `mypage.com` certbot needs to access it (as plain http).

I have tested allot of combinations of the config files and made sure that my router is forwarding both port 443 and 80. So my thought is that certbot has changed something in apache2 that blocks http connections. Has anyone had this problem or an idea what the solution could be.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: I haven't had the ability to test your suggestion, I'll let you know asap

Comment: Sounds good, I’m certain I can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Certbot doesn’t change much, it adds a redirect to .htaccess and disables / enables .conf files for the site you’re working with. It sounds like Apache May have crashed.

Try the following.

I can’t comment because my reputation isn’t high enough. (Kind of dumb because this isn’t an answer it’s a request for more information.)

```
service status apache2



ufw status
```

Make sure 80 & 443 are allowed for tcp

If they aren’t use

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp

sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

Also, run this

```
sudo ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

Then run

```
sudo netstat -anl | grep 80

sudo netstat -anl | grep 443
```

Please comment all results to this answer.